# How to slice middle element from list

Tags: python, slice

Rather simple question. Say I have a list like:

```
a = [3, 4, 54, 8, 96, 2]
```

Can I use slicing to leave out an element around the middle of the list to produce something like this?

```
a[some_slicing]
[3, 4, 8, 96, 2]
```

were the element `54` was left out. I would've guessed this would do the trick:

```
a[:2:]
```

but the result is not what I expected:

```
[3, 4]
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the difference between the slicing you are talking about and poping out an element from a list?...I honestly don't see any difference?...what is your point here of calling it slicing?..rather than deleting an element?

Comment: Because I don't want to remove an element from the list, I want to unpack its elements leaving out one in the middle: E.g: `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 = a[:2:]` (which of course does not work)

Comment: People if you are going to downvote, please leave a comment so I know why you thought the question had no merit? Otherwise there's nothing I can do to fix it and there's nothing I can learn from it to avoid in the future.

Comment: I believe the question was, whether you can pop with a single slice, to which the answer is no. See also, this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/89391).

Comment: Iron Fist, the big difference is that the former returns a list while the latter returns None. for those who like clean, elegant, solutions, being able to pass the result of an operation onto the next can be important.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot emulate pop with a single slice, since a slice only gives you a single start and end index.

You can, however, use two slices:

```
>>> a = [3, 4, 54, 8, 96, 2]
>>> a[:2] + a[3:]
[3, 4, 8, 96, 2]
```

You could wrap this into a function:

```
>>> def cutout(seq, idx):
        """
        Remove element at `idx` from `seq`.
        TODO: error checks.
        """
        return seq[:idx] + seq[idx + 1:]

>>> cutout([3, 4, 54, 8, 96, 2], 2)
[3, 4, 8, 96, 2]
```

However, [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) will be [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757658/89391). The list pop function is defined in [listobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/69276f6f697cc0f6737fb3509b1a769a1d3fbdd0/Objects/listobject.c#L911).

Comment: Thanks miku, I was wondering if there might be a way to do that using a single slice of the list but I guess the answer is simply "no".

Answer (score 8):

To remove an item in-place call:

```
your_list.pop(index)
```

It will return the removed item and change `your_list`.

Comment: However on large lists this could be quite slow as everything after `index` needs to be shifted forward.

Comment: On large lists it is significantly faster than the slice copy aproach. `timeit.timeit('your_list.pop(1)', setup='your_list=range(10**6)', number=1000)` → `1.010901927947998`; 
`timeit.timeit('your_list = your_list[:4] + your_list[5:]', setup='your_list=range(10**6)', number=1000)` → `23.652629137039185`

Comment: @KlausD., thanks for the timeit. Linked your answer in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

To work on any size list:

```
a.pop((len(a)-1)//2)
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Slice the two parts separately and add those lists

```
a[:2] + a[3:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [3, 4, 54, 8, 96, 2]
>>> a_ = [list(j for idx, j in enumerate(a) if idx != 2)]
>>> [3, 4, 8, 96, 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

It is the easiest answer:

> >>>a = [3, 4, 54, 8, 96, 2]
>
> >>>a.remove(54)
>
> [3, 4, 8, 96, 2]

Comment: This is not a good solution as if the number is unknown but only the location/inex is wanted to be filtered out.